# Debugging this OCaml code? Functional Programming

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
let rec fold_inorder f acc t =
match t with
| Leaf -> acc
| Node (l, n, r) -> f (fold_inorder f acc l) (f n (fold_inorder f acc r))
```

I'm trying to print the infold of a tree as following :

```
fold_inorder (fun acc x -> acc @ [x]) [] (Node (Node (Leaf,1,Leaf), 2, Node (Leaf,3,Leaf))) = [1;2;3]
```

I'm getting an error saying my [x] is

```
This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list
```

I'm really not sure what to do from here. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of `fold_inorder`, what type do you expect `f` to have?

If I look at this call:

```
f n (fold_inorder f acc r)
```

it appears that the first parameter of `f` is a new value from a tree node and the second parameter is an accumulated value.

But in your test call you define `f` like this:

```
(fun acc x -> ...)
```

This suggests that the first parameter is the accumulated value and the second parameter is a new value from a tree node.